# How to get unix process ID when running java -jar command

Tags: bash, unix, sh

Is it possible to get the process id of a standalone java application in unix when we run `java -jar` command. I am using this command to start the application

```
java -jar application.jar > application-console.out 2>&1 &
```

and to get the process id I am using this command

```
processID=$(ps aux | grep 'application.jar' | grep -v 'grep' | awk '{print $2}')
```

but my problem is the previous command will search any java jar process for the **application.jar** but what I am looking for is the one that has been just started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PID of the last executed command is in the `$!` shell variable:

```
java -jar application.jar > application-console.out 2>&1 &
echo $!
```